# Is there a clean way to cover the Dwolla-imposed fee on behalf of users?

Tags: dwolla

In our early test/launch of our product we would like to sponsor the $.25 Dwolla charge when a payment above $10 is made.  Is there any clean way to do this?  Clearly the transactions know the developer account information in order to make facilitator fees possible, but you can't set a negative facilitator fee.  I can think of the hacky option of pairing every real transaction above $10 with a $.25 transfer from the developer account, but I am looking for something that will be transparent to users if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no clean way to pay the transaction fee as a facilitator, unfortunately.  This is an interesting case, and a negative facilitator fee would probably be the best way to solve it.  I'll bring up this potential feature with our team!

For now, however, the hacky solution of reimbursing the recipient or sender of $0.25 is the only viable solution.

Comment: If Dwolla is interested in looking more like a white-box service, it would be helpful to allow the facilitator to bear the fee, while also keeping a facilitation fee in place - ie, facilitator charges a total of $.50, $.25 of which will go to Dwolla - so the client doesn't see Dwolla as a middle-man.